# Integral of function and its derivative, multi-dimension

Tags: calculus, integration

Is the following statement true? If so, how can I prove it?

$f = f(x,a)$

$\int \left(f(x,a_1)\int f(x,a_2)dx\right)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int f(x,a_1) dx \int f(x,a_2) dx$

Comment: Yes, see [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not true. I'm assuming that you're using the notation that $\int f dx$ stands for *all* primitive function of $f$ with respect to $x$. Consider for example $f(x,a) = (a+1)x + 1$ with $a_1 = -1$ and $a_2 = 0$. Then, 
$$LHS = \int \left( \int (x+1) dx\right) dx = \int \left(\frac{x^2}2 + x + C_1\right)dx = \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^2}{2} + C_1 x + C_2$$
$$RHS = \frac{1}{2}(x+D_1)\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + x + D_2\right) = \frac{x^3}{4} + \frac{x^2}{4}(D_1 + 2) + \frac{x}{2}(D_1 + D_2) + D_1D_2.$$